# Connect MySQL via SSH with R (RMySQL)

Tags: mysql, r, ssh

I have ssh user/pwd like this:

```
ssh inf:
username="hentyus", 
password="D&dfkucuny@", 
host="39.116.135.84", 
port=5842)
```

And I want to connect database use R(RMySQL),here is database inf:

```
dbname = "yutyts",
username="yutyts_data", 
password="dfkdficlsp", 
host="rr-sodk90usk7.mysql.rds.aliyuncs.com", 
port=3306
```

how can I connect it in R ,thank you  for your help !

Comment: Don't publish your ssh passwords. Delete and change your password. Have you looked at [RMySQL](https://www.r-bloggers.com/accessing-mysql-through-r/) blog.

Comment: This is not a really pwd.

Comment: You want R to use SSH to connect to MySQL? If you have an R program locally you can use `ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 r-sodk90usk7.mysql.rds.aliyuncs.com` and get your R program to connect to mysql `localhost:3306`

Comment: there is error : ssh: connect to host rr-sodk90usk7.mysql.rds.aliyuncs.com port 22: Connection timed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a SSH connection mapping the local 3306 port to the remote datbase server:

```
ssh -L 3306:rr-sodk90usk7.mysql.rds.aliyuncs.com:3306 39.116.135.84 -p 5842
```

Your R program will then connect to localhost:3306 for a database connection.

Comment: there is a error when entry pwd: admin@39.116.135.84: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

Comment: Try reading errors and applying this the current access information you have.

Answer (score 0):

Aliyun has an excellent documentation and knowledge base for issues, you most likely will find the answer in there.
They also have detailed walk-throughs for problem solving like this one which might be your issue: https://help.aliyun.com/knowledge_detail/91707.html

Sorry for the link-only answer, but in this case it's more a pointer to Aliyun KB that for this topic provides more answers than SO:)